# Memory Error while opening sql script in python

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to open a sql script in python but this piece of code is giving Memory error as the sql script is very huge(22GB!).

```
 # Open and read the file as a single buffer
 fd = open('prob.sql', 'r')
 sqlFile = fd.read()
 fd.close()
```

Comment: What is your question? If the size of the file is greatest than available memory it won't fit in memory, full stop.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the `read()` function in this case since it tries to load the entire file.

You could iterate through the file line by line:

```
with open('prob.sql', 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        do_something(line)
```

With the `with` construct you don't need to worry about closing the file handle.

Check out other options [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).